# :active:focus pseudo element doesnt get applied to div on safari

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have 3 div elements side by side and on clicking them, i see a blue focus border for maybe half a second and then it disappears. To resolve this issue I added an :active:focus state and set the outline: none. This works on chrome, firefox, ie but not on safari. Any pointers about how to go about it?

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 85px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block.active {
  background-color: #bddcfc;
  border-color: #278efc;
  outline: none;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: $color-lighter;
  border-color: $color-light;
}

.block.active:hover {
  background-color: #bddcfc;
  border-color: #278efc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block" tabindex="0">1</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">2</div>
<div class="block" tabindex="0">3</div>
```

Comment: If the blue border you're seeing is caused by `outline`, you should be able to apply `outline: none` to the base element without needing any pseudo-classes. Can you put this problem into a reproducible snippet here?

Comment: Ive added the snippet, Also I cannot put the outline: none to the base element as I need to support keyboard tab.

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue in the latest Safari (10.1.2). Not getting an additional blue outline.

Comment: Ive removed the css active focus which sets outline to none and now you will see the flicker. If I put that piece of code back, it works in chrome, firefox, ie but not in safari.

Comment: @phantomsays You mention IE, so I must ask. Is this about Safari on Windows? In other words, Safari v5?

Comment: it is safari on mac Version 10.0.3 (12602.4.8). I tested on ie using browserstack. What i see is that the active focus class does not get applied to the div. If i force apply it from the inspector I do not see the flicker anymore on mac.